# Python regex stop matching after string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am currently trying to match the following cases, which works most of the time, but I'll explain the  exception in a second:

- someword.something.lis
- something.lis

However, matches are also made for the case: `something.lis.some.bad.values.here.after.the.string`

My current regex is:

```
f".+{user_input_string}|{user_input_string}"
```

however, I need to regex matching to stop kind of like (lets say and exclamation mark is a stop symbol):

```
f".+{user_input_string}!|{user_input_string}!"
```

Comment: Why do you mean by adding `.+` at the start? Are you using `re.match`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a positive lookahead assuming you don't wish to capture the stop symbol:

```
f".+{user_input_string}(?=!)|{user_input_string}(?=!)"
```

Tangentially, `.+` makes no sense. You could simplify it to:

```
f".*{user_input_string}(?=!)"
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment, and thanks for the answer!